# apt-get update or apt-get install not working

Tags: ubuntu

sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install not working I am getting following errors please help

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cheese cheese-common gnome-video-effects libcheese-gtk21 libcheese3
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0
  libcogl-common libcogl-pango0 libcogl9 libmx-1.0-2
Suggested packages:
  gnome-video-effects-frei0r
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cheese-common gnome-video-effects libcheese-gtk21 libcheese3
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0
  libcogl-common libcogl-pango0 libcogl9 libmx-1.0-2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cheese
1 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,807 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libcogl9 libcogl-pango0 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-1.0-0 cheese
  cheese-common libcheese3 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0
  libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0 libmx-1.0-2 libcheese-gtk21 gnome-video-effects
  libclutter-1.0-common libcogl-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libcogl9 i386 1.10.0-0ubuntu2
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libcogl-pango0 i386 1.10.0-0ubuntu2
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libclutter-1.0-0 i386 1.10.6-1~precise1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libclutter-gst-1.0-0 i386 1.5.4-0ubuntu2
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe cheese i386 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe cheese-common all 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe libcheese3 i386 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 i386 1.2.0-0ubuntu1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 i386 0.1.4-2build1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0 i386 0.0.2.1-2ubuntu3
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libmx-1.0-2 i386 1.4.3-0ubuntu1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe libcheese-gtk21 i386 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe gnome-video-effects all 0.4.0-1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libclutter-1.0-common all 1.10.6-1~precise1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libcogl-common all 1.10.0-0ubuntu2
  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cogl/libcogl9_1.10.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cogl/libcogl-pango0_1.10.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/clutter-1.0/libclutter-1.0-0_1.10.6-1~precise1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/clutter-gst/libclutter-gst-1.0-0_1.5.4-0ubuntu2_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cheese/cheese_3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cheese/cheese-common_3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cheese/libcheese3_3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/clutter-gtk/libclutter-gtk-1.0-0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/clutter-imcontext/libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0_0.1.4-2build1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/clutter-gesture/libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0_0.0.2.1-2ubuntu3_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mx/libmx-1.0-2_1.4.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cheese/libcheese-gtk21_3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-video-effects/gnome-video-effects_0.4.0-1_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/clutter-1.0/libclutter-1.0-common_1.10.6-1~precise1_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cogl/libcogl-common_1.10.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

it seemed to be working fine before but i dont know what got installed that it started showing so many errors.

The other solutions already provided for this issue dont work for me as I am behind an authenticated proxy server. my ip is 172.31.77.59, my dns servers are 172.31.100.8 and 172.31.100.9 and my proxy server is 172.31.100.29

i searched some commands. the output of cat /etc/network/interfaces is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

maybe that helps in solving the problem

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to /etc/apt/conf and insert http_proxy="http://username:password@server:port".

You should also set the systemwide variable as export http_proxy... .Put this into your ~/.bashrc and restart.

Comment: i have included details in my /etc/apt/apt.conf file could you please elaborate how to export in ~/.bashrc

Comment: Just write "export http_proxy=..." like above and without the ". This will only take effect after a restart.